# Bitshifting to read/write data

Tags: java

I am sending 2 integers as one long in Java, and cannot work out for the life of me how to send these across properly using bit shifting.

I have a method to create the long:

```
public long create(int one, int two){
return      (one <<32 & two);
}
```

First of all, is this correct? (To send the two integers in one long together)

Secondly, if I want to then access either one or two, how do I go about that?

Is it a simple case of:

```
   public static int getOne(long theLong) {
        return (int)theLong >> 32;

    }
```

Or is there something a little more complicated?

Some guidance is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When shifting an `int` value the second operator (the shift width) is `&`’ed with 31, so `someInt << 32` is `someInt`. Cast your `int` to `long` before shifting: `(long) someInt << 32`, this will now give the result you expected.

Comment: Thanks for that, how about for returning a result? I can shift back by 32 bits for the someInt, but how do I return the Int that has not been shifted? Is simply returning (int)theLong, going to do the job, as it will ignore everything after 32 bits?

Comment: Obviously you need to extract the two combined `int` values separately: the first one is in the 32 upper bits, requiring a `>>> 32` (if you don’t know how `>>>` differs from `>>`, *please* go read up on operators in Java), the second one can be obtained by a simple `& 0xffffffff`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public long create(int one, int two){
    return ((long) one << 32) | (two & 0xFFFFFFFFL);
}
```

The way you are sending the data should support multiple `int` values if it supports `long` e.g. for `DataOuput` uses `writeInt()` instead of `writeLong()`