# Primitive DataType Casting in java - Internal Logic

Tags: java, types, casting, bit-manipulation

Guys i want to understand , how the widening or narrow implicit casting is internally implemented in java.I know that it involves bit fiddling.

For example:

```
//implicit
int i =2400;
long a = (long)i; 

//Explicit  
 float d = (float) 2.23423;
```

***Updates:***

I wrote this post after looking at the question 
posted here [Bitshifting to read/write data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351337/bitshifting-to-read-write-data)
.Peter Lawrey gave the following answer.

```
public long create(int one, int two){
    return ((long) one << 32) | (two & 0xFFFFFFFFL);
}
```

To re-iterate same,widening conversion like above happens at the machine level more or less with smiliar  same logic mentioned above by peter.

kindly let me know your valuable comments.

Comment: JLS Chapter 5 describes conversion types available in Java: [http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html]. The implementation of it is platform dependent and generally occurs at the machine code level.

Comment: Have a look at [this article](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html) about narrowing and widening primitive conversions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java uses the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) standard machine code instructions supported by your CPU. As such Java does not implement this functionality using something you can break down further.

For conversion from double to float.

- the sign is preserved
- exponent is truncated, however if the number is too large it goes to infinity, if to small, it goes to zero.
- both formats have an implied top bit which is 1, this is unchanged.
- the top 23 bits of the mantissa is kept (with optional rounding of the 24th bit)

For float to double the process is similar except fields are extended.

However this is all done in the floating point processor unit and Java plays no part in how it happens.

Comment: @mazaneicha:at the machine code level, what @inovaovao
says happens.

Comment: @Suresh S, He does say what happens at the code level but he has confused what happens with unsigned int/long values (which Java doesn't have) with what happens for float/double

Answer (score -1):

A double has 64 bit, whereas a float has 32 bit. When you cast a double into a float you simply drop the first 32 bits.

Viceversa when you widen you just add as many 0 bits to fill the larger type, for instance you add 32 zeros in fron of the 32 bits of an int to make a long.

Comment: -1: You are confusing 64-bit long with 64-bit double.  If you dropped the first 32-bit of a 64-bit double you would get useless random data. BTW: the extending of 0 bit to convert from int to long is correct for unsigned int values (which Java doesn't have)

Comment: @Peter You are right: for doubles it's a bit more complicated. Do you know the details?